# Cython thinks a constructor has an extra argument

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to build the MultiNEAT project from GitHub. https://github.com/peter-ch/MultiNEAT

I am running python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Cython version 0.27.3 and gcc version 5.4.0. When I follow the GitHub instructions to build with Cython I get the following error

```
_MultiNEAT.cpp:19088:166: error: no matching function for call to ‘NEAT::Genome::Genome(unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, unsigned int&, bool&, NEAT::ActivationFunction&, NEAT::ActivationFunction&, unsigned int&, NEAT::Parameters&)’
     __pyx_v_self->thisptr = new NEAT::Genome(__pyx_t_17, __pyx_t_18, __pyx_t_19, __pyx_t_20, __pyx_t_21, __pyx_t_22, __pyx_t_23, __pyx_t_24, (*__pyx_v_a_ps->thisptr));
                                                                                                                                                                      ^
In file included from src/Innovation.h:37:0,
                 from src/Population.h:36,
                 from _MultiNEAT.cpp:589:
src/Genome.h:193:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, NEAT::ActivationFunction, NEAT::ActivationFunction, unsigned int, const NEAT::Parameters&, unsigned int)
         Genome(unsigned int a_ID,
         ^
src/Genome.h:193:9: note:   candidate expects 10 arguments, 9 provided
src/Genome.h:189:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, NEAT::ActivationFunction, NEAT::ActivationFunction, const NEAT::Parameters&)
         Genome(unsigned int a_ID, unsigned int a_NumInputs, unsigned int a_NumHidden, unsigned int a_NumOutputs,
         ^
src/Genome.h:189:9: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 9 provided
src/Genome.h:186:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome(std::ifstream&)
         Genome(std::ifstream &a_DataFile);
         ^
src/Genome.h:186:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
src/Genome.h:183:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome(const char*)
         Genome(const char *a_filename);
         ^
src/Genome.h:183:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
src/Genome.h:170:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome(const NEAT::Genome&)
         Genome(const Genome &a_g);
         ^
src/Genome.h:170:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 9 provided
src/Genome.h:167:9: note: candidate: NEAT::Genome::Genome()
         Genome();
         ^
src/Genome.h:167:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 9 provided
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

However, when I check the Genome.h file it clearly has a constructor with 9 arguments, and it seems Cython is duplicating the ActivationFunction argument for some reason that I can't figure out. Any insight into building this project with Cython would be appreciated.

**Note:** When I first tried to build it gave me an error about a class not having a function `Age()` I simply removed the reference to `Age()` from that print statement to continue and got the current error.

Comment: Presumably it was you that also reported this in the project issue tracker? https://github.com/peter-ch/MultiNEAT/issues/36

Comment: Yes, it was me. I don't really know how responsive the creator is, so I also asked the question here to hopefully find a solution quicker.

Comment: I actually need to figure this out in my current print.

Comment: 10 parameters are needed in the constructor, you need to provide/add a_NumLayers-parameter in the pyx-File. This was forgotten by the author in a change 12 days ago.